# Can't change TabBar Item icon that is set in Storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbaritem, xcode-storyboard

In my app, one of the TabBar Items needs a custom icon, depending on context within the app.
I'm using this code to accomplish that:

```
item1 = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Jij" image:inactiveIcon selectedImage:activeIcon];
```

and that works just fine. **As long as I don't set an icon in the Storyboard.**

In my experiments, I found out that running above code from the `AppDelegate's` `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` executes the code before the `TabBar` even exists. At least that is what I think.

So, in order to have at least a temporary placeholder icon, I have to set it in the Storyboard. But somehow, that keeps my code from updating the image.

I even looked into subclassing the `TabBarController`, just to make sure that the icon is loaded in time.

Please point me at the mistakes in my code, logic or findings.

To summarize the question:

How come I cannot change an `TabBarItem` image once it is set in the Storyboard?

Answer (score 4):

You can also set the property Render As of your tab bar images within your asset catalog directly.
[image]

There you have the option to set the property to Default, Original Image and Template Image.
Hope this will help :)

Comment: I tried all three options, but still the image from the asset catalog prevails, i.e.: it remains in place after I run my method. 
However, if I don't set that image in the Storyboard, it shows up empty at first, but after running my method, the custom image IS shown.

Comment: @Sjakelien Select the UITabbarItem and add a run-time attribute 'selectedImage', select Type as 'Image' and give the name of your image as its value. may be this will help you.

Comment: I must be doing something wrong. I tried your suggestion, both WITH and WITHOUT a placeholder image, but the result is the same.

Comment: it worked for me...changing "Render As key from Default image to Original image"....worked.